# Service Principal Authentication to Microsoft Dynamics 365 API issue

Tags: authentication, azure-devops, microsoft-dynamics, azure-powershell

For the life of me I cannot figure this out.
I am trying to write a **PowerShell** Script that will get a list of solutions in a tenant

The Url to do this is as following: **https://(MyCRM).dynamics.com/api/data/v9.x/solutions**

Service principal items I have are: **ClientId, ApplicationId, ClientSecret**

In my case I am using Invoke-WebRequest

How do I build the Authentication part of the Invoke-WebRequest, to successfully get the request through?

Answer (score 0):

so someone pointed me to a solution :)
basically its a two step process:

1. you get the access token from https://login.microsoftonline.com
2. than you use the token in your authorisation header for any calls you do to the server

[Solution](https://www.richardawilson.com/2021/06/calling-dataverse-web-api-in-powershell.html)